# Magento Ajax Request Not Working In Custom Module

Tags: ajax, magento, https

I'm getting this error when trying to make an ajax request in a custom module:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.vossmarket.com/index.php/shoppinglist/index/showLists/product/4294/form_key/6erZKqom1ynOWDKI/qty/1/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.vossmarket.com' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm assuming the problem is that I am calling https from the http, but I'm not able to figure out why it is calling the https.  I've turned off https in the magento config (I changed secure_base_url to http://vossmarket.com and I turned Use Secure URLs in Frontend to "no").  Now all links stay http, but when I visit my custom module, it is still redirecting (302) to https.  This happens to every link http://vossmarket.com/shoppinglist (my custom module), any other route stays http, but any route that hits my module in any ways 302s to https

Any ideas what might be happening or the best way to fix it?

Comment: No, I ended up having to just run it HTTP. I couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting a file called crossdomain.xml in your web root (accessible by both http and https), ie at http(s)://vossmarket.com/crossdomain.xml

This should help define that cross site origin is allowed between http and https.

In your case, I think the custom module is upset about being accessed over http and is sending the 302 to your browser, so it would be a case of studying the controller action of the custom module to figure out why it is forcing https (instead of asking Magento what the secure URL is).

Actually, if you try this crossdomain.xml you will need the browser to request https out of the http loaded page otherwise I think you will still get the 302 redirect - but with crossdomain.xml in place you should be able to XMLHttpRequest from http://vossmarket.com to https://vossmarket.com

But, you know, often there is good reason for https so I think you should understand why https is being forced and also I don't know about that XML secure="false" - does it really mean an https request is returned over http? I hope not but I don't know.

For more information read up on CORS although your 'cross domain' is http crossing to https.